# Create a new row at the bottom of dataframe and add column sums

Tags: r

I am reading  a csv file from the working directory with the following code:

```
df <- read.csv("test1.csv", header = TRUE,skip =6, nrow =
length(count.fields("test1.csv")) - 12)
```

then changing the column names with the following code:

```
colnames(df) = c("type","date","v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6","v7","v8","v9","v10","v11","v12","v13","v14","v15","v16","v17","v18","v19","v20","v21","v22","v23","v24","total")
```

my data set dimension is 365 rows x 24 columns and I am trying to calculate the column (3:27) sums and create a new row at the bottom of the dataframe with the sums.

data.frame look like this:

[image]

If I try a test with some sample data as follows it works fine:

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = c(3:8, 1:2), x2 = c(4:1, 2:5),x3 = c(3:8, 1:2), x4 = c(4:1, 2:5))
```

x[9,(2:3)] <- apply(x, 2, sum)

but when I try in the csv file that I am working with, the code I am using is as follows:

```
x[366,(3:27)] <- apply(df, 2, sum)
```

but it gives an error like this: "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument"

Could anyone advise me how to resolve this?

Comment: if you run str(df) does it tell you that the last 24 columns are of class numeric or interger? it looks like one or more of them is a character class

Comment: hi, If I do str(df) it says 'num' for last 25 coloumns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`apply(df, 2, sum)` will try to sum all columns, and if the columns `type` and `date` are of a type for which R doesn't have a `sum` method, this will fail. You could try

```
df[366,(3:27)] <- colSums(df[,3:27], na.rm=TRUE)
```

**EDIT**

To identify numeric columns:

```
myNumCols <- which(unlist(lapply(df, is.numeric)))
```

And then

```
df[(nrow(df) + 1), myNumCols] <- colSums(df[, myNumCols], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks Ben for the answer, it creates now the row 366 but the values are saying 'NA' except the last one which is 'Total' showing the sum value, would you know how to rectify this? Thanks

Comment: guys sorted it out, thanks for your help! :) it was showing na due to missing data, so i used: df[(nrow(df) + 1), myNumCols] <- colSums(df[, myNumCols], na.rm = T) solved! cheers!

Comment: @Ayan, added `na.rm=TRUE` to `colSums`

Comment: How to pass on the argument TOTAL to the 366th row in the first column?